# GitHub Webhook not triggering the Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

I want to trigger a pipeline when Pull Request is Merged..ie "action": "closed","merged":"true"

Webhook got 200 response for Jenkins

**pipeline.groovy:**

```
pipelineJob(job_name) {
    parameters {
        stringParam('APP_URL', app_url, 'URL of the Application')
        stringParam('APP_MERGE_STATUS', app_merge_status, 'Merge Status to Trigger Job')
        booleanParam('MERGED', true, 'Flag to Trigger the job')
        stringParam('APP_ARTIFACT_BUCKET', artifact_bucket, 'Bucket url to upload artifacts')
        stringParam('payload')
    }
    triggers {
        genericTrigger {
            genericVariables {
                genericVariable {
                    key("APP_MERGE_STATUS")
                    value("\$.action")
                    expressionType("JSONPath")
                }
                genericVariable {
                    key("MERGED")
                    value("\$pull_request.merged")
                    expressionType("JSONPath")
                }  
            }
            printPostContent(true)
            regexpFilterText("\$action")
            regexpFilterExpression("")
        }
    }
```

Generic Variables I have mentioned are also used to trigger the job without github..[using parameters]

I am not sure how to write the generic trigger variables and regex for the trigger
Scenario: PR is closed and merged

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got the solution..I missed to add "generic-webhook-trigger" in payload url

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins is exposed to the internet, you can subscribe to the webhook in Github itself

[image]

or use [jenkins declarative pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers) to make use of

Comment: Yes In webhooks->Let me select individual events->Pull Request, Payload url: https:jenkins.com/github-webhook/   So this gets 200 response and I am using Scripted Pipeline